# How do I set the Perspective camera using threlte in my svelte app?

Tags: three.js, svelte, sveltekit

I am trying to set the perspective camera using a function. I have a button that I when I click on it will set the camera position. I can make it work if I just reset the camera position, but I want to tween it to make is slowly rotate back to it's original position. When I console.log($camera.position) I do get the current position. When I console.log(camera) I get [image: this]
It looks like there is a method to set subscribe or update. I have tried to set and update the position:

```
function resetCamera() {
        console.log('camera');
        cameras.position.update({position: {x: 30, y: 0, z: 0 }});
    }
function resetCamera() {
        console.log('camera');
        cameras.position.set({position: {x: 30, y: 0, z: 0 }});
    }
```

but then I get the error "Cannot assign to read only property 'position' of object '#'".
Below is the full code that I have. But as I mentioned, I am trying to set the value of the perspective camera without it just snapping back in to place. If I just use my function to make set cameraStart to the value I want, it just snaps in to place. I have tried to tween this value, but I believe this value is just used when the component loads.

```
<script>
    // @ts-nocheck

    import { tweened } from 'svelte/motion';
    import FurnaceScene from '$lib/furnaceScene.svelte';
    import PlateScene from '$lib/plateScene.svelte';
    import TestPlateScene from '$lib/testPlateScene.svelte';
    import { Pane } from 'tweakpane';
    import { browser } from '$app/environment';
    import * as Threlte from '@threlte/core';
    import * as Three from 'three';
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';
    import * as Extra from '@threlte/extras';
    import * as Utils from 'three/src/math/MathUtils';
    import { useThrelte } from '@threlte/core';
    const { camera } = useThrelte();
    console.log('Camera ', $camera.position);
    $camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    let plateData;
    onMount(() => {
        getPlateLocation();
    });

    function resetCamera() {
        console.log('camera');
        cameras.position.update({position: {x: 30, y: 0, z: 0 }});
    }

    //put grid in for dev
    const gridHelper = new Three.GridHelper(40, 40);
    const axesHelper = new Three.AxesHelper(10);

    let cameraStart = {
        position: { x: 0, y: 30, z: 0 }
    };

    //declare global function so it can be called from parent
    if (browser) {
        window.handleResetFromComponent = function () {
            console.log('You did it!');
            $camera.position = {x: 0, y: 30, z: 0}
        };
    }

    async function getPlateLocation() {
        const respone = await fetch('api/plates');
        plateData = await respone.json();
        //console.log(plateData);
    }
</script>

{#if plateData}
    <Threlte.PerspectiveCamera position={cameraStart.position} lookAt={{ y: 0 }}>
        <Threlte.OrbitControls
            maxDistance="30"
            minDistance="10"
            enableDamping
            on:end={(e) => console.log(camera)}
        />
    </Threlte.PerspectiveCamera>

    <!-- Add light -->
    <Threlte.AmbientLight color="white" intensity={0.2} />
    <Threlte.DirectionalLight color="white" intensity={2} position={{ x: 10, y: 8, z: 6 }} />

    <!-- grid helper -->
    <Threlte.Object3DInstance object={gridHelper} />
    <Threlte.Object3DInstance object={axesHelper} />

    <!-- Furnace component -->
    <FurnaceScene />

    {#each plateData as plate}
        <PlateScene {plate} />
    {/each}

    <!-- <TestPlateScene /> -->
{/if}
```